# Discrete Deconvolution in R

Tags: r, convolution

I have a set of data with two slightly overlapping peaks that I would like to deconvolve into their respective components.

The measured data (`variable h`) is a function of the first event (`variable f`) and a second unmeasured event (typically denoted as `variable g`). The data set may be reconstructed using the following code:

```
h <- as.numeric(c(256, 208, 139, 406, 316, 226))
f <- as.numeric(c(256, 208, 139))
t <- as.numeric(c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8))
test <- data.frame(h, f, t)
```

In the data above, the `variable t` represents time. The first event begins just after `t=0` and the second event begins just after `t=4`. My objective is to figure out how much of the second event (where `h = 406, 316, and 226`) are attributable to the residual effects of `f` and how much is due to `g`. In other words, I would like to solve for `variable g` at `t = 5, 6, and 8`.

Both of these events can be assumed to follow a monoexponential decay function. When the log(10) of `h` is plotted against `t` the resulting graph looks like this:

[image: plot]

In researching this problem, it appears that the R `decon` package is only suitable for evaluating measurement error problems, rather than performing this type of discrete deconvolution analysis. Does anyone know of an alternative method to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Is the rate of exponential decay a given or is that a model parameter?

Comment: It's a model parameter that I have fit using data from event #2. The rate value that I obtained was equal to 0.1990 with the plateau constrained to equal 0.